# Power for Strip lights

Tags: power-supply, rgb, power-consumption

How many watts does a 12v 300 led - 5 meter strip light use roughly, is there a wattage per smd/led there 5050, I have a 5amp 12v = 60watts I think and was told that's more than enough, and I have a 1.5amp 12v = 18 watts I think. There was no watts per meter specified.
Rule of thumb sort of answer

Comment: a 5050 LED has 3 LED chips, in total it uses 60 mA at 3 V (roughly) so that is 0.18 Watt per 5050 LED. So the 18 Watts supply could power at least 100 LEDs.

Comment: My rule of thumb - provide a data sheet.

Comment: So a 2 amp/24watt might do 2 meters then - 120 LEDs.                            If I use 2 wire single colour can I connect the strip light to the power cable without any boxes, nice and clean under a glass shelf

Answer (score 1):

-Color: Cool White
- View angle:120°
- Working Voltage: 12VDC
- LED Quantity: 300 leds/5 Meter
- Working Current/meter: 1.2A
- Output power: 72W /5 Meter
- Total Working Current: 6A